# How can I verify jwt token from oauth provider?

Tags: express, next.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, next-auth

I'm developing a project with next-js/next-auth as my front-end, and express as my back-end server. So what I'm trying to figure out is once I've been authenticated with a third-party provider (Github, Google, etc) and I put the token through jwt callback on session, when I send this token using axios to my backend, How should I verify that this is a valid token for an authenticated user?.

Or perhaps should I use sign-in call back to save this authenticated user to a db with its corresponding token and then I can verify this token against the one stored on db?

Or am I completely misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: If you're using strictly OAuth2 and you have a backend, it's better to use authorization_code and don't pass the tokens to through your frontend. Have the user redirect to an endpoint and exchange the `code` for an access token in Node. No need to verify is the access token is authentic, because you got it straight from their endpoint.

Comment: @Evert Interesting approach but not a clue of how to achieve that, once I'm authenticated and redirected from Google to my callback url, Inside next-auth config I have a few call back from where I have access to this access_token, so where should I store this access token in a way that I can retrieve it and send it to the back end, and how back end should know this is a valid token?

Comment: Yeah it's the _recommended_ approach for OAuth to avoid getting access_tokens in the frontend. I can't specifically answer how to do this next-auth, I wouldn't be surprised that it assumes everything happens in React. Still possible to do this securely, but there's just more than needs to be done / can go wrong.

Comment: That said one great way to test if the access token you got is valid, is by using it =) Just hit an API point that gives you user information, and now you also know who it belongs to. If the access token _was_ a JWT, you need Google's JWKS endpoint and validate the JWT against their public keys. The JOSE library will let you do this.

Comment: @Evert thanks, doing a further research I found that I should use signin callback of next-auth to make a call to my backend with this access token and store it into my db with user related info to use it in the following calls and verify the user and the validity of the access token with the corresponding provider. Since at front end level I just have access to user id, mail and user name, I should send this data to recover user in the back end retrieve the access token and validate it

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't trust that you'll be able to verify on the frontend. You should make a request with it for the info you need. If the user is not logged in, the call should fail.

On the backend, you can verify that a JWT hasn't been tampered with by verifying it's signature. For that, you'll generally need the public key which is often stored on a jwks endpoint. Further validation then requires validating some of the claims including whether it's expired or not.

However, this exposes one of the weaknesses of OAuth and JWTs in that, even if you successfully verify and validate the token, the user may have logged out. If the user logs out with the provider, the token had no way of updating. It's only until that token is sent to the provider/authz server will it fail (if that server has properly marked it as invalid when the user logged off). But, if you're using that solely within the confines of your server, there's no way to tell.

So, the ideal way is, yes, to use it. The provider will tell you whether they're currently logged, often their son's user not authorized or similar type of error.

But, if you're using next-auth, it should do most of this for you.  Have a look at their [Client API](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client) And the different varieties they have for sessions. And you can use JWT or db methods as shown on their [options page](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options)

Unless you can't afford the call to your backend, then use a session token stored in the browser or secure cookie, and have it mapped to the user and/or JWT on the backend. That way, you don't risk leaking data or, worse, the access the JWT (access token) provides.

Comment: The appendix of the JWS RFC (7515) has a couple walkthrough examples that take you through the steps to validate in the strict sense of the term. But, generally you should use some trusted library to avoid risking a small hiccup causing a big headache. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7515#appendix-A